# How to make cassandra result in datewise (timestamp) sorted manner with paged results?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

i created table with following fields

```
CREATE TABLE snwv2jobs.testtab (
  testtabid bigint,  
  posteddate timestamp,
  description text,   
  year bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY ((testtabid,year),posteddate)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (posteddate DESC)
```

but on retrieving data , the result shows:

testtabid  - 35
posteddate - 2016-11-25 17:40:29+0530 
year       -2016

testtabid  - 36
posteddate - 2016-11-25 17:40:31+0530
year       -2016

testtabid  - 34
posteddate - 2016-11-25 17:40:25+0530
year       -2016

testtabid  - 37
posteddate - 2016-11-25 17:40:34+0530
year       -2016

testtabid  - 38
posteddate - 2016-11-25 17:40:37+0530
year       -2016

i need the result in this manner :

testtabid  - 38
posteddate - 2016-11-25 17:40:37+0530
year       -2016

testtabid  - 37
posteddate - 2016-11-25 17:40:34+0530
year       -2016

testtabid  - 36
posteddate - 2016-11-25 17:40:31+0530
year       -2016

testtabid  - 35
posteddate - 2016-11-25 17:40:29+0530
year       -2016

testtabid  - 34
posteddate - 2016-11-25 17:40:25+0530 
year       -2016

Comment: Cassandra order data by cluster key in a partition key value. In your case for a single testtabid and year data will sorted by posteddate desc

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the data in a year are sorted by posteddate, Here is the schema

```
CREATE TABLE snwv2jobs.testtab (
  testtabid bigint,  
  posteddate timestamp,
  description text,   
  year bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY ((year),posteddate, testtabid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (posteddate DESC, testtabid DESC)
```

There is a problem with the above schema If you have huge data generate in a year. all the data will go to same partition.

So you need to add month and week in the partition key. So here is the schema that will sort all the data in a week

```
CREATE TABLE snwv2jobs.testtab (
  testtabid bigint,  
  posteddate timestamp,
  description text,   
  year int,
  month int,
  week int,
  PRIMARY KEY ((year,month,week),posteddate, testtabid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (posteddate DESC, testtabid DESC)
```

If you have less data you can remove week from the partition key or if you have huge data generate in a day you can add day to the partition key instead of week.

Comment: Thanks Ashraful Islam .That's worked.
will u pls chek this question also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837826/data-reference-and-updation-in-cassandra-tables

Comment: Hi Ashraful Islam. Will u pls check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906913/sorting-order-in-cassandra-result