# Sorting order in cassandra result

Tags: sorting, cassandra, datastax, cql

I created table

```
CREATE TABLE testtab (
  testtabmainid bigint,
  testtabid timeuuid,
  posteddate timestamp,
  description text,  
  year bigint,
  month bigint,
  day bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY ((year,month,day),posteddate,testtabmainid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (posteddate DESC,testtabmainid desc);
```

then on

```
SELECT testtabmainid,posteddate,year,month, day FROM testtab;
```

i got result like this

> **testtabmainid** **/** **posteddate** **/**  **year** **/**  **month** **/**   **day**
>
> 90 **/**  2016-12-01 11:19:11+0530 **/**  2016 **/**  11 **/**    30
>
> 89 **/**  2016-11-30 16:21:58+0530 **/**  2016 **/**  11 **/**    30
>
> 88 **/**  2016-11-30 16:13:33+0530 **/**  2016 **/**  11 **/**    30
>
> 91 **/**  2016-12-01 11:20:42+0530 **/**  2016 **/**  12 **/**    1

the last row  is not in sorted order. I need  the last row (testtabmainid =91 ) on the top

i need to sort table in testtabmainid in desc manner

Answer (score 2):

You queried without specifying any `WHERE` clause. This produces results ordered by the `TOKEN` function applied to your partition key data.

In order to satisfy your query you need to change first of all the table definition to:

```
CREATE TABLE testtab (
  testtabmainid bigint,
  testtabid timeuuid,
  posteddate timestamp,
  description text,  
  year bigint,
  month bigint,
  day bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY ((year,month,day),testtabmainid,posteddate)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (testtabmainid desc,posteddate DESC);
```

and then change your query to:

```
SELECT testtabmainid,posteddate,year,month, day 
FROM testtab 
WHERE year=2016 AND 
      month=12 AND 
      day=1;
```

The key point is that data is ordered by your `CLUSTERING KEY` only **inside** a partition, and that's why you need to filter your queries with a `WHERE` clause to obtain *your* order.

If you want to keep the *posteddata DESC* order, you'll need to create another table (the one you already have is fine) and insert/update both tables.